# check-in gwt code using SVN in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, gwt, subclipse

I am trying to check-in a gwt project created in eclipse using the standard instructions.

Once the code is completely check-ed i see that the project directory is created in the server but the actual content is not checked in.

I am wondering why I am seeing this issue.

Thanks,
Bhavya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are using Subclipse and you used the Team > Share Project option.

The way this option works is that it creates a folder in the repository and then checks it out into the root of your project locally.  This converts your local project into a valid SVN working copy.

The next step is to Add and Commit your resources.  Rather than doing this automatically, Subclipse initiates a Synchronize.  This should open the Eclipse Synchronize view and show all your resources as outgoing changes.  You can then commit them.

The reason it does this is to give you a chance to add items and setup SVN properties before committing.  For example, suppose you have a "bin" folder or WEB-INF/classes folder that holds the compiled output.  You do not usually want to commit this folder, so you can first add its parent and then add this folder to the Ignore list of the parent so that it is not committed.  You may similarly have some files you do not want to commit.  The Synchronize view gives you a convenient UI for doing this.